# What data type is returned by the following python code?

Tags: python

In the following python code what type is returned by the function **bruteforce_list**?

```
import paramiko, sys, os, socket, threading, time
import itertools,string,crypt

PASS_SIZE = 5

def bruteforce_list(charset, maxlength):
    return (''.join(candidate)
        for candidate in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.product(charset, repeat=i)
        for i in range(1, maxlength + 1)))

letters_list = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$&()'

for i in bruteforce_list(letters_list, PASS_SIZE):
     print i
```

I have never seen for loops used the way they are after the join(candidate) in this way.  I am very new to python and an overall explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mad Physicist stated it returns a generator expression.

The syntax to create generator expressions is the same as that for list comprehensions, except that list comprehensions use square brackets.

Generator expressions take the general form:

(*expression* for *variable* in *iterable*)

You can optionally include conditions:

(*expression* for *variable* in *iterable* if *conditions*)

Finally, you can have multiple for clauses:

(*expression* for *variable_a* in *iterable_a* for *variable_b* in *iterable_b*)

The generator expression does not *materialize* every element at once; instead, you can iterate over the generator to get an element at a time.  This can be effective when you want to avoid holding large collections in memory.

Comment: So logically it is equivalent to some code that produces a yield command in it somewhere.  Kind of hard to wrap your head around it as a beginner.

Answer (score 3):

In general in python, you can show the type of a variable using `type()` function.
so try doing something like this in you loop `print type(i)`, that should give you a brief idea what is `i`.